# Maven doesn't create the class with right path

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I'm following the maven tutorial from https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/. So, first I type the following to generate the pom.xml file and the source files.

`mvn -B archetype:generate       -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app     -DartifactId=my-app`

Then I go to the `my-app` folder and compile using `mvn-compile`. However, on inspecting the App's main class, by typing `javap target\classes\com\mycompany\app\App`, I get the following.

```
Warning: File .\target\classes\com\mycompany\app\App.class does not contain class target\classes\com\mycompany\app\App
Compiled from "App.java"
public class com.mycompany.app.App {
  public com.mycompany.app.App();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

My question is, why do I get the warning at the top, that `App.class` does not contain class `target\classes\com\mycompany\app\App`, and how can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is shown because `javap` assumes you are executing it at the root of the package structure (if you don't provide a classpath argument). Try `cd target\classes` then `javap com\mycompany\app\App`.

Comment: I still get the warning.